# vim substitution of generic number

Tags: vi

I'm trying to substitute some sequence of char by another in a file with vim.
I've got this in a file : 
aname;1234
anothername;1456
again;1478
againBis;10253
things;10547
thingsBis;12457
etc...

and I would like to replace the ";1" sequence on each line where the number is 4 chars long by a ";01" sequence so that the number is 5 chars long.

I tried in vi :

```
:1,$s:;1...:;01...:g
```

but the substitution results in :
aname;01...
anothername;01...
again;01...
againBis;10253
things;10547
thingsBis;12457
etc...

It removes the chars after the "1"...
Someone can help ???
Tahnks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following command should do what you want:

**UPDATE:**

`:1,$s:;\(1[0-9]\{3\}$\):;0\1:g`

Comment: Thanks for your answer but vim answers "Pattern not found ;\(1[0-9]\{3\} \)" so I tried without "\(" and "\)" and it results with a very bad substitution. Any other idea ??

Comment: you should add backslash('\') before `(` and `)`. this pair of parentheses is used for [backreference](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html).

Comment: I tried with the backslash as you wrote but then I had the message "Pattern not found..." That's why I tried without the "'\(" which does not work either.

Comment: "pattern not found" means this pattern do not match any text in your file, can you tell me more about the layout and content of your file?

Comment: my file is a basic text file but containing around 36000 lines with data like this : 
`aname;1234 
anothername;1456 
again;1478 
againBis;10253 
things;10547 
thingsBis;12457`

Comment: what's between a number and a word? a space or a tab?

Comment: between a number and a word, there is a new line. each line is aword;anumber.

Comment: according to your description, i had updated the command and hope this time it will work out :)